# How to inherit Interface

Tags: delphi

I create a tlb library from a `dll`. So I've got some `com` object.
I want to extend the interface but I can't.

_Ckdu_cache:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: _Ckdu_cache
// Flags:     (4560) Hidden Dual NonExtensible OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0137B6A2-76D0-3E27-A13C-557542A3AAD5}
// *********************************************************************//
   _Ckdu_cache = interface(IDispatch)
['{0137B6A2-76D0-3E27-A13C-557542A3AAD5}']
function Get_ToString: WideString; safecall;
function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool; safecall;
function GetHashCode: Integer; safecall;
function GetType: _Type; safecall;
function close: Byte; safecall;
function get_capabilities: Integer; safecall;
function read(buf: PSafeArray; num_bytes: Integer): Integer; safecall;
function seek(offset: Int64): Byte; safecall;
function get_pos: Int64; safecall;
function set_tileheader_scope(tnum: Integer; num_tiles: Integer): Byte; safecall;
function set_precinct_scope(unique_id: Int64): Byte; safecall;
procedure Dispose; safecall;
function add_to_databin(databin_class: Integer; codestream_id: Int64; databin_id: Int64; 
                        data: PSafeArray; offset: Integer; num_bytes: Integer; is_final: Byte; 
                        add_as_most_recent: Byte; mark_if_augmented: Byte): PByte1; safecall;
```

Cockdu_cache :

```
// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoCkdu_cache provides a Create and CreateRemote method to          
// create instances of the default interface _Ckdu_cache exposed by              
// the CoClass Ckdu_cache. The functions are intended to be used by             
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the         
// server of this typelibrary.                                            
// *********************************************************************//
  CoCkdu_cache = class
    class function Create: _Ckdu_cache;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _Ckdu_cache;
  end;
```

My class :

```
type
  TKduCache = class(CoCkdu_cache)
```

My constructor :

```
constructor TKduCache.Create(_targetID, _cachePath: String);
var
  cache : _Ckdu_cache;
begin
  cache:= inherited Create;
end;
```

**Error:
EIntfCastError with message 'Interface not supported'**

I created the other method without extend, as follows:  `cache:= Cockdu_cache.Create;` but I got the same error. I followed this method to another `COM` Object creation and they work. But this doesn't work for me. How can I use **_Ckdu_cache** methods?

**Additional:**

```
unit kducache;

interface

uses imagecachestatus, jpipdatasegment, kdu_mni_TLB, globalvalues, SysUtils, Dialogs,
    System.Classes, System.Variants, Winapi.ActiveX, jpipdatabinclass,
  jpipresponse;

type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;
type
  TKduCache = class
  private
    { private declarations }
    //The cache file to use. Null if its not using a chace file.
    cacheFile     : TFileStream;
    Flags         : Word;
    cachePath     : String;
    status        : IImageCacheStatus;
    //The targetID for the image as given by the JPIP server.
    //Should be a unique hash for the image and thus serves
    //as a good way of naming the cache file.
    targetID      : String;
    //The amount of new data placed in this object via the
    //addDataSegment method starting after the initial
    //readCacheFromFile method.
    newData       : Integer;
    //This flags indicates if the server has to be loaded/saved to disk.
    iamPersistent : Boolean;
    class var maxCacheSize  : LongInt;
    cacheExists   : Boolean;

    class function uByteToInt(_x : array of Byte) : TIntArray;
    class function getCacheFiles(_cachePath : String) : TStringStream;
  protected
    { protected declarations }
  public
    FCache: _Ckdu_cache;
    { public declarations }
    procedure setImageCacheStatus(imageCacheStatus : IImageCacheStatus);
    procedure setInitialScope;
    procedure addDataSegment(_data : TJPIPDataSegment);
    class procedure updateCacheDirectory(_cachePath : String; maxSize : Double); overload;
    class procedure updateCacheDirectory(_cachePath : String); overload;
    function getNewDataSize : Integer;
    function getTotalDataSize : Integer;
    function isDataBinCompleted(_binClass : TJPIPDatabinClass; _streamID : Integer; _binID : Integer) : Boolean;
    function Close : Boolean;
    function addJPIPResponseData(jRes : TJPIPResponse) : Boolean;
    function writeCacheToFile : Boolean;
    function readCacheFromFile : Boolean;
    function buildCacheModelUpdateString(force : Boolean) : String;
    function getCacheFile : TStringStream;
    constructor Create(_targetID : String; _cachePath : String); virtual;
//    constructor Create(_targetID : String; _cachePath : String; _iamPersistent : Boolean); overload;
  published
    { published declarations }
  end;
implementation

{ TJHV_Kdu_Cache }

{ TKduCache }

//Main constructor used when you want to use a cache file.
constructor TKduCache.Create(_targetID, _cachePath: String);
begin
  FCache:= CoCkdu_cache.Create;
  targetID:= _targetID;
  cachePath:= _cachePath + '\' + targetID + '.cache';
  cacheExists:= true;
  Flags:= fmOpenReadWrite;
  if _cachePath = '' then
    cacheExists:= false
  else
  begin
    Flags := fmCreate;
    cacheFile:= TFileStream.Create(cachePath, Flags);
  end;
  newData:= 0;

  cacheFile.Free;
  if cacheExists then
    readCacheFromFile;
end;
```

Where i call :

```
TKduCache.Create(jpipTargetID, 'C:\Users\myComputer\Desktop\WorkStation\cache');
```

Comment: The implementation of the object that implements the interface lives in the COM server. You cannot extend it using class inheritance.

Without knowing precisely what you are trying to achieve, it's very hard to recommend a way forward.

Comment: i am tryin to use some methods like add_to_databin method to jpeg2000 caching. i am using kakadu sdk, but it does not have, delphi library. just dll file. so i convert dll file to tlb. I can use methods in other classes. But for this, i got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to use inheritance. Do not declare a derived class. Create an instance of the interface like this:

```
cache := CoCkdu_cache.Create;
```

Then call methods on `cache` directly.

Comment: i always do like your code. But this class gives an error as above. What is the meaning of that error, can you explain me :/

Comment: The code in your question is not written like that. In your question you ask about inheritance, and using an invalid `cache := inherited Create`. It's difficult if you ask about one thing, and then expect an answer about something else. Why didn't you ask about your original problem?

Comment: i mean, i tried to 2 ways. first one is inheritence and the other one is, like yours. But compiler gives me an same error. Directly call or inherit call does not change anything, they' re both occure same error.

Comment: The code in my answer, given the code in your question, does not result in `EIntfCastError`. If you are experiencing, `EIntfCastError`, then your code differs in some way.

Comment: The `CoCkdu_cache` is nothing more than a factory that gives you interface references and as has been said, there's no need to inherit from it. You can write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/Qp3PKNc2).

Comment: i tried your way, but error same. Thank you for helping, i have no experiencing. May be _Ckdu_cache is defined different. i will check source code in c#. thanks again

Comment: Please show the implementation of `CoCkdu_cache.Create`

Comment: i changed q and added (kdu_mni_TLB is COM Objects unit)

Comment: Please show the implementation of `CoCkdu_cache.Create`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in java, class extends the _CKdu_cache and  call methods using super() without creating object. And that works. java using native jar library but i am using com objects

Comment: I found the error, delphi couldnt find dll file, so i added the dll same folder with exe. But i forgot the change, changed dll file, so why it crush is